# Use full iPhone X resolution in Adobe AIR app

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, ios10, iphone-x

The relatively new iPhone X introduces a new screen resolution. It doesn't seem possible to use the full screen size and 3x resolution. I'm using the latest AIR SDK (30) and it doesn't make any difference for this matter. I've searched the web and the only thing I've encountered so far is the splash images (ex: *Default-Landscape-812h@3x~iphone.png*) but nothing about the application supported resolution itself.

At this point, I'm assuming that it is not (yet) supported by Adobe AIR. Any clues / suggestions / solutions? Cheers!

Comment: Describe that "not supported". Flash content resets the stage's width and height to what is provided by device or browser, the max dimensions are at 8K, I think, so I doubt iPhoneX is beyond that.

Comment: What have you actually tried so far?

Comment: I had the very same issue until I included `Default-812h@3x.png`